# Operación MySQL con variables recurrentes

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) > 0 
      THEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) ELSE NULL
    END
  ) AS "variable1",
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) > 0 THEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) / 2 ELSE NULL
     END
  ) AS "variable2",
  COUNT(Run.id) AS "variable3"
FROM Run;
```

¿Como puedo hacer (Variable1+Variable2)/Variable3? Necesito hacerlo fuera del sql?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad tienes dos opciones:

- sumar directamente
- o sumar metiendo todo en una subconsulta

**Directamente**

```
SELECT (
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) > 0 
      THEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) ELSE NULL
    END
  ) +
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) > 0
      THEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) / 2 ELSE NULL
     END
  ) )/
  COUNT(Run.id) AS total
FROM Run;
```

**Encapsulando en subconsulta**

```
SELECT (variable1+variable2)/variable3 total FROM (
    SELECT
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) > 0 
          THEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) ELSE NULL
        END
      ) AS variable1,
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) > 0 
          THEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) / 2 ELSE NULL
         END
      ) AS variable2,
      COUNT(Run.id) AS variable3
    FROM Run  
  ) c1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer desde fuera de la consulta, a partir de los resultados de esta.

```
SELECT  (Variable1+Variable2)/Variable3
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) > 0 then (Run.penalties DIV 50) ELSE NULL END) as "variable1",
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) > 0 then (Run.penalties MOD 50)/2 ELSE NULL END) as "variable2", COUNT(Run.id) as "variable3"
    FROM Run 
) a
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puede hacerlo en el **`select`** del mismo modo:

**Schema (MySQL v 5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Run (
  id INT,
  penalties INT
);
INSERT INTO Run (id, penalties) VALUES (1,40);
INSERT INTO Run (id, penalties) VALUES (2,100);
INSERT INTO Run (id, penalties) VALUES (3,80);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) > 0 
    then (Run.penalties DIV 50) ELSE NULL END) as variable1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) > 0 
    then (Run.penalties MOD 50)/2 ELSE NULL END) as variable2, COUNT(Run.id) as variable3,
(SUM(CASE WHEN (Run.penalties DIV 50) > 0 
    then (Run.penalties DIV 50) ELSE NULL END) + SUM(CASE WHEN (Run.penalties MOD 50) > 0 
    then (Run.penalties MOD 50)/2 ELSE NULL END))/COUNT(Run.id) AS operado
FROM Run ;

| variable1 | variable2 | variable3 | operado     |
| --------- | --------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 3         | 35        | 3         | 12.66666667 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)